# My Postgres database wasn't using my index; I resolved it, but don't understand the fix, can anyone explain what happened?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My database schema in relevant part is there is a table called User, which had a boolean field Admin. There was an index on this field Admin.

The day before I restored my full production database onto my development machine, and then made only very minor changes to the database, so they should have been very similar.

When I ran the following command on my development machine, I got the expected result:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM user WHERE admin IS TRUE;

Index Scan using index_user_on_admin on user (cost=0.00..9.14 rows=165 width=3658)
Index Cond: (admin = true)
Filter: (admin IS TRUE)
```

However, when I ran the exact same command on my production machine, I got this:

```
Seq Scan on user  (cost=0.00..620794.93 rows=4966489 width=3871)
Filter: (admin IS TRUE)
```

So instead of using the exact index that was a perfect match for the query, it was using a sequential scan of almost 5 million rows!

I then tried to run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM user WHERE admin IS TRUE;` with the hope that `ANALYZE` would make Postgres realize a sequential scan of 5 million rows wasn't as good as using the index, but that didn't change anything.

I also tried to run `REINDEX INDEX index_user_on_admin` in case the index was corrupted, without any benefit.

Finally, I called `VACUUM ANALYZE user` and that resolved the problem in short order.

My main understanding of vacuum is that it is used to reclaim wasted space. What could have been going on that would cause my index to misbehave so badly, and why did vacuum fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It was most likely the `ANALYZE` that helped, by updating the data statistics used by the planner to determine what would be the best way to run a query. `VACUUM ANALYZE` just runs the two commands in order, `VACUUM` first, `ANALYZE` second, but `ANALYZE` itself would probably be enough to help.
2. The `ANALYZE` option to `EXPLAIN` has completely nothing to do with the `ANALYZE` command. It just causes Postgres to run the query and report the actual run times, so that they can be compared with the planner predictions (`EXPLAIN` without the `ANALYZE` only displays the query plan and what the planner thinks it will cost, but does not actually run the query). So `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` did not help because it did not update the statistics. `ANALYZE` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` are two completely different actions that just happen to use the same word.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL keeps a number of advanced statistics about the table condition, index condition, data, etc...  This can get out of sync sometimes.  Running `VACUUM` will correct the problem.

It is likely that when you reloaded the table from scratch on development, it had the same effect.

Take a look at this:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/maintenance.html#VACUUM-FOR-STATISTICS

Comment: Thanks for the link, any ideas on why my call to analyze the query was insufficient?

Comment: actually `ANALYZE` corrects the problem.  `VACUUM ANALYZE` happens to do both.  Also as a note, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` does not do any analysis of the tables beyond what EXPLAIN does.  What it does is run the query and compare to cost estimates.

Answer (score 1):

A [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html) seems a good solution for your issue:

```
CREATE INDEX admin_users_ix ON users (admin)
    WHERE admin IS TRUE;;
```

Has no sense to index a lot of tuples over a identical field.

Comment: Only one thing.  This would not have been used in this case if the planner wouldn't have used the other index.  I do note however that a partial index is a good practice with bools.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is the most likely explanation.

Your index is useful only when a very small number of rows are returned (btw, I don't like to index bools for this reason-- you might consider using a partial index instead, or even adding a where admin is true since that will keep your index only to the cases where it is likely to be usable anyway).

If more than around, iirc, 10% of the pages in the table are to be retrieved, the planner is likely to choose a lot of sequential disk I/O over a smaller amount of random disk I/O because that way you don't have to wait for platters to turn.  The seek speed is a big issue there and PostgreSQL will tend to try to balance that against the amount of actual data to be retrieved from the relation.

You had statistics gathered which indicated that the table was either smaller than it was or there were more admins as a portion of users than you had, and so the planner used bad information to make the decision.

VACUUM ANALYZE does three things.  First it freezes tuples visible to all transactions so that transaction wraparound is not an issue.  Then it allocates tuples visible to no transactions as free space.  Neither of these affected your issue.  However the third is that it analyzes the tables and gather statistics on the tables.  Keep in mind this is a random sampling and therefore sometimes can be off.  My guess is that the previous run, it grabbed the page with lots of admins and thus grossly overestimated the number of admins of the system.

This is probably a good time to double check your autovacuum settings because it is also possible that the statistics are very much out of date elsewhere but that is far from certain.  In particular, cost-based vacuum settings have defaults that sometimes make it so that vacuum never fully catches up.